# Accessing Webcam or Microphone using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Does it possible to access microphone or Webcam using Visual Basic Scripting ?
i tried searching on google but didn't find the good answer .

I just need to ask if there is any easy method to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the product supplies a COM object which you can load via VBScript this can be done, otherwise not. Some webcams can be viewed at with an IP address if the cam can also be controlled this way you could in theory load this page with VBScript and interact with it. You would, however, best use a language that is better suited for this kind of work like eg Ruby.